# python code error. ValueError: y should be a 1d array, got an array of shape (56000, 10) instead

Tags: python, data-science, logistic-regression

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
logistic_regression = LogisticRegression(random_state = 10)
logistic_regression.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred_logistic_regression = logistic_regression.predict(X_test)
print(y_pred_logistic_regression.shape)
```

> ValueError: y should be a 1d array, got an array of shape (56000, 10)instead

Comment: About your question: 
You should ask a question and not just post the error and code. Like include the line number on which you have the error. Where do you get the train/test data x and y?
You should add which package you are using as a label, like: sklearn, tensorflow etc.
In order to find the problem you should check the shapes of the `X_train`, `y_train`, `X_test`. Most probably you have problem with the `y_train`. 
 You can also add a code block for the code above.

Comment: print(X_train.shape)(56000, 784)
print(y_train.shape)(56000, 10)
print(X_test.shape)(14000, 784)
print(y_test.shape)(14000, 10)
 hi thank you for your help  i can mention all the included packages . and shapes also could you please help me out . Thanks

Comment: You forgot to show the part where you load the `y_train`. I'm guessing you are making an OCR of some sort. The `y_train` should should be a single array with 56000 elements.
Can you add the first few rows of the `y_train` something like `print(y_train[:5])`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `y_train` array is out of shape, assuming you are working with one hot encoded classes, the solution would be to convert it into a class index array:

```
logistic_regression.fit(X_train, y_train.argmax(axis=1))
```

example:

```
>> y_train
array([[0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])
# after conversion:
>> y_train.argmax(axis=1)
array([2, 3, 4, 0])
```