# y should be a 1d array, got an array of shape {} instead.".format(shape)

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I am currently working on a project to detect and recognise handwritten signatures. I am able to detect the signatures and store it in a "images" folder and I am storing the labels in a "labels.txt" file.

Now, I am trying to build a model to recognise the handwriting and give me the prediction. However, I am encountering the following error

> "y should be a 1d array, got an array of shape {}
> instead.".format(shape)"

I referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73970907/python-code-error-valueerror-y-should-be-a-1d-array-got-an-array-of-shape-56) question but am not sure as they were using train_test_split module.

Here is my code:

**Checking the labels and images:**

```
import os

# Get the list of images
images = os.listdir("images/")

# Remove any non-image files from the list
images = [img for img in images if img.endswith(".jpg") or img.endswith(".jpeg") or img.endswith(".png")]

# Get the list of labels from the label text file
with open("labels.txt", "r") as f:
    labels = f.readlines()

# Strip the newline characters from each label
labels = [label.strip() for label in labels]

# Print the number of images and labels
print("Number of images:", len(images))
print("Number of labels:", len(labels))
```

**Loading the dataset into "images" and "labels" array**

```
import os
import numpy as np
import cv2

def load_images_labels(images_folder, labels_file):
    images = []
    labels = []
    
    # Read images from the folder
    for filename in os.listdir(images_folder):
        if filename.endswith('.jpeg') or filename.endswith('.jpg'):
            image = cv2.imread(os.path.join(images_folder, filename))
            images.append(image)
    
    # Read labels from the file
    with open(labels_file) as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        for line in lines:
            label = line.strip()
            labels.append(label)
    
    # Convert the lists to numpy arrays
    images = np.array(images)
    labels = np.array(labels)
    
    return images, labels

# Load the images and labels from the folder and file
images, labels = load_images_labels('./images', './labels.txt')

images = images[:2]
labels = labels[:5]

print(images)
print(labels)
```

**Building, Compiling and Training the model**

```
import tensorflow.keras as keras
import pandas as pd

# image size should be 28*28 so reshape using .reshape(-1.28,28,1)
# y, the list of names

#array[:75]


from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import (
    Dense,
    Conv2D,
    MaxPool2D,
    Flatten,
    Dropout,
    BatchNormalization,
)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(75, (3, 3), strides=1, padding="same", activation="relu", 
                 input_shape=(28, 28, 1)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPool2D((2, 2), strides=2, padding="same"))
model.add(Conv2D(50, (3, 3), strides=1, padding="same", activation="relu"))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPool2D((2, 2), strides=2, padding="same"))
model.add(Conv2D(25, (3, 3), strides=1, padding="same", activation="relu"))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPool2D((2, 2), strides=2, padding="same"))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(units=512, activation="relu"))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))
model.add(Dense(units=num_classes, activation="softmax"))
# Preprocessing the images to be ready for the model
images = images.astype("float32") / 255.0
images = np.array([image.reshape(-1, 28, 28, 1) for image in images])

# One hot encode the labels
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder

label_encoder = LabelEncoder()
labels = label_encoder.fit_transform(labels)
labels = labels.reshape(-1, 1)

onehot_encoder = OneHotEncoder()
labels = onehot_encoder.fit_transform(labels).toarray()

num_classes = labels.shape[1]

# Compile the model
model.compile(
    optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001),
    loss="categorical_crossentropy",
    metrics=["accuracy"],
)

# Train the model
history = model.fit(x=images, y=labels, batch_size=32, epochs=10, validation_split=0.01)

# Evaluate the model
test_loss, test_accuracy = model.evaluate(images, labels, verbose=0)
print(f"Test Accuracy: {test_accuracy:.4f}")
```

**Error Message:**

> ---

```
--------- ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
> last) Cell In[10], line 9
>       6 from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder
>       8 label_encoder = LabelEncoder()
> ----> 9 labels = label_encoder.fit_transform(labels)
>      10 labels = labels.reshape(-1, 1)
>      12 onehot_encoder = OneHotEncoder()
> 
> File
> ~/miniconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/utils/_set_output.py:142,
> in _wrap_method_output.<locals>.wrapped(self, X, *args, **kwargs)
>     140 @wraps(f)
>     141 def wrapped(self, X, *args, **kwargs):
> --> 142     data_to_wrap = f(self, X, *args, **kwargs)
>     143     if isinstance(data_to_wrap, tuple):
>     144         # only wrap the first output for cross decomposition
>     145         return (
>     146             _wrap_data_with_container(method, data_to_wrap[0], X, self),
>     147             *data_to_wrap[1:],
>     148         )
> 
> File
> ~/miniconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/_label.py:116,
> in LabelEncoder.fit_transform(self, y)
>     103 def fit_transform(self, y):
>     104     """Fit label encoder and return encoded labels.
>     105 
>     106     Parameters    (...)
>     114         Encoded labels.
>     115     """
> --> 116     y = column_or_1d(y, warn=True)
>     117     self.classes_, y = _unique(y, return_inverse=True)
>     118     return y
> 
> File
> ~/miniconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py:1202,
> in column_or_1d(y, dtype, warn)    1193         warnings.warn(    1194
> "A column-vector y was passed when a 1d array was"    1195            
> " expected. Please change the shape of y to "    (...)    1198        
> stacklevel=2,    1199         )    1200     return
> _asarray_with_order(xp.reshape(y, -1), order="C", xp=xp)
> -> 1202 raise ValueError(    1203     "y should be a 1d array, got an array of shape {} instead.".format(shape)    1204 )
> 
> ValueError: y should be a 1d array, got an array of shape (5, 5)
> instead.
```

I would really be grateful for any help that I can receive.

Comment: full error message please!

Comment: @hpaulj Sorry, I have added the complete error message.

Comment: The error occurs in `labels = label_encoder.fit_transform(labels)`; I'd examine `labels`, pay close attention to its `shape`.  And review the docs for this `fit_transform`.  The initial error as different from this extended display.

Comment: The error message tells you very clearly what is going wrong: `LabelEncoder.fit_transform` needs to be passed a 1-dimensional array, and you pass it a 2-dimensional array instead. Please **read the documentation** in order to understand what should be in the array and how it corresponds to your situation. For reference for future questions, please read [ask] and [mre] and https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/. If you can see where in the program the error occurs, the next step is to show a **small, focused** example around that part of the program.

Comment: Looking further up your code I see a `print(labels)` line.  Did you look at that?  Does it look right?  You didn't show it to us.  Regarding the initial question, not only did you summarize the whole error, but you posted the wrong part, the line with the `format` in it, not the more informative `"ValueError: y should be a 1d array, got an array of shape (5, 5)"`.  In the long run debugging will be easier if you learn to read the error messages.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I see. I realise that I should have asked the question more concisely and properly check up the docs. Regardless, thank you for your advise. I will be sure to follow it up.

Comment: @hpaulj Sorry. I am new to this. I will try to properly frame the question.

Comment: Questions like this about ML projects are common.  Often posters are new to both ML, python, numpy and even coding.  Tutorials provide a lot of code, but with little guidance as to what to do when the data isn't quite right, especially with mixed sizes.  But it's hard for others to help the problem lies primarily in data that is imported - we can't see or test any of that data.  So the clearer you are in asking the question, the more likely you'll get a useful comment or answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the issue was fairly simple and it was completely my fault. I was executing this code on the Colab platform. And I forgot to execute the previous block of cell, before running "Building, Compiling and Training the model" - this cell.